# Spring boot Model mapper Unsatisfied Dependency exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit-runner

I have the spring boot application that runs without exception when I remove the basic application test. But it shows the following exception when I add the application test class

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:39.421+05:30","@version":1,"message":"The following profiles are active: development","logger_name":"com.tmobile.u2.uprising.adjustment.AdjustmentApplicationTests","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:44.914+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HikariPool-1 - Starting...","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:44.958+05:30","@version":1,"message":"Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource","thread_name":"main","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:48.794+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HikariPool-1 - Start completed.","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:49.315+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [\n\tname: default\n\t...]","logger_name":"org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:49.847+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}","logger_name":"org.hibernate.Version","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:49.857+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found","logger_name":"org.hibernate.cfg.Environment","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:49.864+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist","logger_name":"org.hibernate.cfg.Environment","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:50.076+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}","logger_name":"org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:50.839+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect","logger_name":"org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:54.583+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.","logger_name":"org.hibernate.orm.deprecation","thread_name":"main","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:56.251+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:57.467+05:30","@version":1,"message":"HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:58.129+05:30","@version":1,"message":"\r\n\r\n***************************\r\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\r\n***************************\r\n\r\nDescription:\r\n\r\nParameter 0 of constructor in com.tmobile.u2.uprising.adjustment.factory.AdjustmentFactory required a bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper' that could not be found.\r\n\r\n\r\nAction:\r\n\r\nConsider defining a bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper' in your configuration.\r\n","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
{"@timestamp":"2018-04-23T18:10:58.177+05:30","@version":1,"message":"Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4e096385] to prepare test instance [com.tmobile.u2.uprising.adjustment.AdjustmentApplicationTests@1e5aacd9]","logger_name":"org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)\r\n\tat org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)\r\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)\r\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)\r\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)\r\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)\r\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)\r\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)\r\n\tat org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)\r\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adjustmentFactory' defined in file [C:\\Users\\karthikar\\Desktop\\BackUP\\ADJUSTMENT\\adjustmentpublisher\\target\\classes\\com\\tmobile\\u2\\uprising\\adjustment\\factory\\AdjustmentFactory.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)\r\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)\r\n\t... 26 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)\r\n\t... 44 common frames omitted\r\n","APP_NAME":"adjustmentPublisher"}
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 27.377 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.tmobile.u2.uprising.adjustment.AdjustmentApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.tmobile.u2.uprising.adjustment.AdjustmentApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.021 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adjustmentFactory' defined in file [C:\Users\karthikar\Desktop\BackUP\ADJUSTMENT\adjustmentpublisher\target\classes\com\tmobile\u2\uprising\adjustment\factory\AdjustmentFactory.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.modelmapper.ModelMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  AdjustmentApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load Applicat...
```

Here is my AdjustmentApplicationTests class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AdjustmentApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

and my AdjustmentApplication is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AdjustmentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdjustmentApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and following is my factory class:

```
@Component
public class AdjustmentFactory {

    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public AdjustmentFactory(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }
......
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me what am doing wrong over here.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. This help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010544/how-do-i-autowire-3rd-party-classes-with-annotations-in-spring#answer-36010696

Answer (score 9):

Add the bean configuration in any configuration file or starter application file

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
 return new ModelMapper();
}
```

we should define the beans before we use in our components, else we will get the same issue every time

Answer (score 2):

Try adding your package path to your beans with the following:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.yourProject.components")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.yourProject.entities")
@SpringBootApplication
public class AdjustmentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdjustmentApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

where ".components" and ".entities" are your own folders you keep your classes in.

You can also try to to specify your Application classas below for your tests:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = AdjustmentApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AdjustmentApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: I have added your updates in to it. But still the same error occurs.What else may be the cause???

Comment: Tried to add @Configuration annotation to your AdjustmentApplication.class?

Comment: There's also @EnableAutoConfiguration. Read more here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M1/api//org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html

Answer (score 1):

try to add this Class after main() method

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}
```

Then your AdjustmentApplication will be as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AdjustmentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdjustmentApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```