# SpringBoot - Register a bean before @Component's get scanned

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a component Login that depends on ValidatorService. ValidatorService is being injected/autowired in the Login constructor. ValidationServiceImpl is provided by an external API, so I can't just annotate it as @Service.

```
@Component
class Login {

   @Autowire
   public Login (ValidatorService validator) {

   }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Starter.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to register ValidatorService as a bean before @Components get scanned. Is there a way to get ApplicationContext instance before starting the application?

**SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE**

**UPDATE**

I need to pass a validationId that I'll get from main(args) to this external API.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String validationId = args[0];
    ValidatorService service = ExternalValidationAPI.getValidationServiceImp(validationId);
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do that? Spring already understands that beans can depend on other beans, and it knows to create them in order. If by "external API" you mean simply that you can't use an annotation to component-scan the implementation class, you can use an `@Bean` method (or even just `@Import(ValidationServiceImpl.class)` if it only has one constructor).

Comment: @chrylis - The only thing I have is the Interface ValidationService and a API to retrieve the instance of it based on validationId being passed as argument to this API. please see my UPDATE about this validationId

Comment: You can still call `ExternalValidationAPI.getValidationServiceImp(validationId)` from an `@Bean` method and return the result as your Spring bean.

Comment: does `ValidationServiceImpl` is annotated with any of the stereotype annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem **creating a Configuration class and declaring a Bean to handle the instantiation of the external service** that will be injected later (as some people have suggested). In order to retrieve the program arguments I **autowired DefaultApplicationArguments** to retrieve program arguments with **getSourceArgs()**:

```
@Configuration
public class ValidatorConfig {

@Autowired
DefaultApplicationArguments applicationArguments;

@Bean
public ValidatorService validatorService()
{
    String validationId = applicationArguments.getSourceArgs()[0];

    return ExternalValidationAPI.getValidationServiceImp(validationId);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to declare it as a bean as such in one of your configuration classes:

```
@Bean
public ValidatorService validatorService(){
    return new ValidatorServiceImpl();
}
```

This will then autowire in the ValidatorService implementation class at the point it is needed. This method needs to go in an `@Configuration` class (your `Starter` class is one).

There's a good example of how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010544/how-do-i-autowire-3rd-party-classes-with-annotations-in-spring).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can solve your problem with the help of the `@Configurable` annotation.

Annotate your Login class with `@Configurable` instead of `@Componenet`, and when the `ValidatorService` object becomes available, you can initiate the `Login` object with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a ValidationService bean :

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ValidationService validationService(@Value("${validationId}") String validationId) {
        return new ValidationServiceImpl(validationId);
    }

}
```

and run the program this way : java -jar program.jar --validationId=xxx

Comment: I've updated my post with a very important piece of information. is there a way to retrieve the parameters I receive in Main class inside this configuration class?

Comment: You can inject either JVM Args or Program arguments : ValidationService validationService(@Value("${systemProperties.validationId}") String validationId) or ValidationService validationService(@Value("${validationId}") String validationId)

Comment: How to do that with program arguments? I found a workaround of setting as a property as soon as I receive it from main(args) <System.setProperty("validation-id", args[0])> but I don't feel good doing this :)

Comment: program arg : java -jar program.jar --validationId=xxx   ,  jvm arg    java -jar program.jar -DvalidationId=xxx

Comment: honestly, this is the first time I see this format --validation=xx

Comment: I'm my case arguments will be passed like:  java -jar program.jar xxx, and then I can get it from args[0]